# how we can resolve the moodle filter wiris error?

Tags: math, filter, moodle, mathtype, wiris

I get the following exception:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'selectNode' on 'Range': the
>   given Node has no parent.
>
> at n.t.selectNode
>   (/theme/yui_combo.php?3.15.0/datatype-xml-parse/datatype-xml-parse-min.js&3.15.0/io-xdr/io-xdr-min.js&3.15.0/io-form/io-form-min.js&3.15.0/io-upload-iframe/io-upload-iframe-min.js&3.15.0/queue-promote/queue-promote-min.js&3.15.0/io-queue/io-queue-min.js&3.15.0/event-simulate/event-simulate-min.js&m/-1/editor_atto/rangy/rangy-min.js&3.15.0/handlebars-base/handlebars-base-min.js&3.15.0/handlebars-compiler/handlebars-compiler-min.js&3.15.0/timers/timers-min.js&m/-1/editor_atto/editor/editor-min.js&m/-1/editor_atto/plugin/plugin-min.js&m/-1/atto_title/button/button-min.js&m/-1/atto_bold/button/button-min.js&m/-1/atto_italic/button/button-min.js&m/-1/atto_unorderedlist/button/button-min.js&m/-1/atto_orderedlist/button/button-min.js&m/-1/atto_link/button/button-min.js&m/-1/atto_image/button/button-min.js&m/-1/atto_media/button/button-min.js&m/-1/atto_managefiles/button/button-min.js&m/-1/atto_underline/button/button-min.js&m/-1/atto_strike/button/button-min.js:62:2509)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is pretty unclear. Can you provide any code snippets or a context for the question?

Comment: I am getting this exception in moodle 2.7 while I am using atto_wiris math type
 "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'selectNode' on 'Range': the given Node has no parent."

Due to this some of the jquery and validation not working on the Quiz add page.